# Using the Google Documents equation editor, how can I enter the binomial coefficient?

Tags: google-docs, formatting

It does not appear that you can enter the [binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) or the choose-function of combinatorics. I'm trying to use the parenthesis in the third drop-down menu in the equation editor, but they add standard parenthesis. I want my end result to look like this: [image: binomial coefficient]

Can this be done or must I use a different notation?

Comment: What is the difference between standard and the one/s shown in wikipedia ? Could you re-edit the question to show exactly (the equations in wikipedia are png's so you can place them in your post) which notation you are looking for because I just did it in Google Docs and saw no problems.

Comment: In general if you run into troubles with the equation editor in Google Docs try searching on how to do stuff in LaTeX.. Just keep in mind that google doesn't support all the LaTeX commands for the equations..

Comment: Lipis: The new Google formula editor doesn't support ANY LaTeX that I can see, and the documentation backs that up: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=160749

Comment: @phwd: The standard one is the first one shown in Wikipedia: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/3/8/2/382c5908d125a08662b2fedc22f4d02c.png. Also, I'm not trying to place it anywhere in a Google Doc, but as part of a much larger equation.

Comment: if you open the equations editor and click around to have some symbols vsible and you open the preview image in another browser-tab (or check the url of that symbol), you see that it uses google-chart api and its tex backend. it does not support all latex-things but it is for sure pretty much tex involved in that piece of software.

Answer (score 14):

It is true that the notation for the binomial coefficient isn't included in the menu, but you can still use it by using the automatic shortcuts.

When in the equation editor, type \choose

[image: Type \choose]

then press space

[image]

That's it!

**Reference**

- [Use equations in a document | Google Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160749?hl=en)

Comment: more than 4 years later and I still need to do it this way :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/) seems to use the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas) (or better the tex backend of the chart API) to display equations.

So, as long as

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chl=%5Cbinom%7Bx%7D%7By%7D
```

(which is url-encoded for `\binom{x}{y}` at the end) results in

[image]

you will have problems to enter that formula.

Answer (score -1):

type \choose and press space bar

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: This is the same answer that Matias Rasmussen gave. Just do this, and you will see what happens.